# Laravel: Pass Parameter to Relationship Function?

Tags: php, laravel

Is it possible to pass, somehow, a parameter to a relationship function?

I have currently the following:

```
public function achievements()
{
     return $this->belongsToMany('Achievable', 'user_achievements')->withPivot('value', 'unlocked_at')->orderBy('pivot_unlocked_at', 'desc');
}
```

The problem is that, in some cases, it does not fetch the unlocked_at column and it returns an error.

I have tried to do something like:

```
public function achievements($orderBy = true)
{
$result = $this->belongsToMany (...)
if($orderBy) return $result->orderBy(...)
return $result;
}
```

And call it as:

```
$member->achievements(false)->(...)
```

But this does not work. Is there a way to pass parameters into that function or any way to check if the `pivot_unlocked_at` is being used?

Comment: You should be fine to do what you are saying. You do need to remember though that the relationship functions act differently if you call them as method over properties. If you use them as properties you get a result set (Collection), but if you call them as methods you get a query builder. If you want to pass parameters to them you obviously have to be calling them as methods, so make sure you do a `->get()` in your calling code: `$member->achievements(true)->get()->(...)` would be equivalent to `$member->achievements->(...)`.

Answer (score 15):

Well what I've did was just adding new attribute to my model and then add the my condition to that attirbute,simply did this.

```
Class Foo extends Eloquent {
    protected $strSlug;

    public function Relations(){
         return $this->belongsTo('Relation','relation_id')->whereSlug($this->strSlug);
    }
 }

 Class FooController extends BaseController {
     private $objFoo;


     public function __construct(Foo $foo){
         $this->objFoo = $foo
     }

     public function getPage($strSlug){
        $this->objFoo->strSlug = $strSlug;
        $arrData = Foo::with('Relations')->get();
        //some other stuff,page render,etc....
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 10):

You can simply create a scope and then when necessary add it to a builder instance.

Example:

User.php

```
public function achievements()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Achievement::class);
}
```

Achievement.php

```
public function scopeOrdered(Builder $builder)
{
    return $builder->orderBy(conditions);
}
```

then when using:

```
//returns unordered collection
$user->achievements()->get();

//returns ordered collection
$user->achievements()->ordered()->get();
```

You can read more about scopes at [Eloquent documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#local-scopes).

Comment: can i pass parameter on ordered() function here ?

Comment: Yes you can.

```
    public function scopeOrdered(Builder $builder, string $orderBy)
    {
        return $builder->orderBy($orderBy);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do more simple, and secure:

When you call the relation function with the parentesis Laravel will return just the query, you will need to add the get() or first() to retrieve the results

```
public function achievements($orderBy = true)
{
if($orderBy) 
    $this->belongsToMany(...)->orderBy(...)->get();
else
    return $this->belongsToMany(...)->get();
}
```

And then you can call it like:

```
$member->achievements(false);
```

Works for the latest version of Laravel.

Comment: Just be aware when doing this that this method no longer behaves like a relationship. You cannot chain it with other conditions. I would recommend using a different name for the method to make this clear, such as `getAchievements()`.

Answer (score -1):

Had to solve this another was as on Laravel 5.3 none of the other solutions worked for me. Here goes:

Instantiate a model:

`$foo = new Foo();`

Set the new attribute

`$foo->setAttribute('orderBy',true);`

Then use the `setModel` method when querying the data

`Foo::setModel($foo)->where(...)`

This will all you to access the attribute from the relations method

```
public function achievements()
{
if($this->orderBy) 
    $this->belongsToMany(...)->orderBy(...)->get();
else
    return $this->belongsToMany(...)->get();
}
```

Comment: There is problem there. You cannot use that with ->with function, when you try, you will get Null. So it's only usable on single models, not in batch. So there will be multiple queries instead of few

Comment: @AidOnline01 just because it did not work for your scenario it does not mean that it is incorrect. This worked great for my use and I believe it would solve the OP's question. Does not deserve your downvote as it can help others ;-)

Comment: as I said before, this is not a relationship function, but an attribute function, so better for it to be `getAchievementsAttribute`. You cannot query it with `with` function, so Model::with('achievements')->get() will fail. That's said I believe this does not answer the question of author